# Using supressions by ID in checkstyle

Tags: java, javadoc, checkstyle

I would like to make checkstyle ignore missing javadoc for `@throws` clauses in tests, but complain in non-tests.

Because supression files do not support subproperties of the [JavadocMethod](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html), I am forced to either ignore javadoc in tests altogether or not at all, with no granularity. This is also the conclusion of [this other question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016848/how-to-ignore-checkstyle-warning-for-missing-throws-for-test-method)

Here's what I'm trying now: could I have two JavadocMethod modules with different id's (e.g. `test` and `notest`) in my checkstyle configuration, and selectively supress the `test` module on non-tests and viceversa?

I cannot get this to work, and I'm starting to think I can't have a duplicate module in checkstyle. Any insights?

Here are my rules regarding JavadocMethod in the configuration xml:

```
<module name="JavadocMethod">
  <property name="id" value="nontest"/>
</module>
<module name="JavadocMethod">
  <property name="id" value="test"/>
  <property name="allowMissingThrowsTags" value="true"/>
</module>
```

And this is my supression file:

```
<suppressions>
   <!-- Supress non-test-doc on tests -->
   <suppress id="nontestdoc" files=".*(?:Test|IT).*java" />
   <suppress id="testdoc" files=".*(?!Test|IT).*java" />
</suppressions>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can have duplicate module in checkstyle.

Tried with 2 `Indentation` module with `tab 2` and `tab 4` respectively. And used the `suppression.xml` like following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress id="IndnA" files=".*\.java"/>
    <suppress id="IndnB" files=".*\.java"/>
</suppressions>
```

and what is the regex `.*(?:Test|IT).*java` and `.*(?!Test|IT).*java` for? Why are you using LookAhead?

please check with files as `.*\.java` whether that is working or not.