# How to fully disable javadoc checking with checkstyle maven plugin

Tags: maven, checkstyle

i want to use the Maven Checkstyle plugin with a custom configuration that tells Checkstyle to not warn or error on missing Javadoc. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ignore CheckStyle warning for missing @throws for test method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016848/how-to-ignore-checkstyle-warning-for-missing-throws-for-test-method)

Comment: Not a duplicate, this question is how to disable it always, not just for a specific file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just found it myself. To fully ignore all javadoc checking for everthing, add this to your checkstyle configuration:

```
    <!-- No need for Javadoc -->
    <module name="JavadocType">
        <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
        <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocVariable">
        <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    </module>
```

Comment: ...  or just remove those modules from the configuration entirely.

Comment: That did not seem to work for me, it seemed to fall back to default configuration.

Comment: Are you sure it works? I still get this those errors: `(javadoc) JavadocVariable: Missing a Javadoc comment.`

Comment: I can confirm that it does not work with ````(javadoc) JavadocVariable: Missing a Javadoc comment.```` . And it is not enough to remove configuration. It still fallbacks to default

Comment: it doesnt work for me either

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 13):

One good option would be configuring a [suppressions filter](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/suppressions-filter.html).

Plugin configuration:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <!-- ... -->
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- ... -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>verify</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <configuration>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
              <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
              <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
              <suppressionsLocation>
                checkstyle-suppressions.xml
              </suppressionsLocation>
              <suppressionsFileExpression>
                checkstyle.suppressions.file
              </suppressionsFileExpression>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <!-- ... -->
</project>
```

`checkstyle-suppressions.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
     "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.0//EN"
     "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_0.dtd">

<suppressions>
  <suppress checks="Javadoc" files="."/>
</suppressions>
```

Then running

```
$ mvn verify
```

Does not output any Javadoc-related Checkstyle errors.

Many other examples on suppressions filters may be found in [checkstyle repository](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/7638c89b9c7e110e399c00dcb59bd783837879e8/config/suppressions.xml#L32).

Comment: You probably want to run `maven-checkstyle-plugin` in the `validate` phase because it makes no sense to compile something that then later doesn't pass checkstyle.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the example with the Gradle 7.3.2 setup.

build.gradle

```
 plugins {
    id 'checkstyle'
}
```

Folder structure (root level).

```
    ├── config
    └── checkstyle
        ├── checkstyle.xml
        └── suppressions.xml
```

Below is the entry in checkstyle.xml to include suppressions.xml

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${config_loc}/suppressions.xml" />
</module>
```

And now you can have the suppressions in the suppressions.xml file to ignore a particular type of check.

for e.g. Below code base will ignore the mentioned checks for all files (regex can be applied to ignore particular matching set of files.)

```
 <suppressions>
    <suppress files="." checks="JavadocMethod"/>
    <suppress files="." checks="JavadocPackage"/>
    <suppress files="." checks="JavadocVariable"/>
    <suppress files="." checks="MissingJavadocMethod"/>
    <suppress files="." checks="JavadocPackage"/>
</suppressions>
```

Now execute the Checkstyle task on consolidated project files by

```
gradle check
```

If specific execution is needed then use checkstyleMain or checkStyleTest to execute checkstyle report on Source files or test files respectively.